# Python ModuleNotFoundError when running tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, python-unittest

I have a Python program that runs correctly as expected, but for some reason I am not able to execute the tests.

In the folder hierarchy, *tests* is a sibling folder of *src* and the error I got when executing tests is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub'
```

Here, the hierarchy plus a MWE of the code:

```
- src/
  - __init__.py
  - dummyA.py
  - main.py
  - sub/
    -__init__.py
    - dummyB.py
- tests/
  - __init__.py
  - test_s.py
```

**src/dummyA.py**

```
from sub.dummyB import Sub
class Sup:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sub_var = Sub()

    def hello_sup(self, s):
        sub_word = self.sub_var.hello_sub(s)
        return f"Super {sub_word}!"
```

**src/sub/dummyB.py** (inside "sub" folder)

```
class Sub:
    def hello_sub(self, a):
        return f"{a}"
```

**src/main.py**

```
from sub.dummyB import Sub
from dummyA import Sup

def main():
    sub = Sub()
    sup = Sup()

    dummy_text = "cat"

    sub_word = sub.hello_sub(dummy_text)
    sup_word = sup.hello_sup(dummy_text)

    print("Sub is:", sub_word) # cat
    print(f"Sup is: {sup_word}") # Super cat!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**tests/test_s.py**

```
from src.dummyA import Sup

def test_sub_sup():
    dummy_sup = Sup()
    expected_res = dummy_sup.hello_sup("cat")
    assert expected_res == "Super cat!"
```

**ERROR log:**

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 162, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/demo/tests/test_s.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.dummyA import Sup
  File "/home/user/demo/src/dummyA.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sub.dummyB import Sub
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub'
```

No matter if I use *pytest* or *unittest*, the error is always the same.
It looks like the system breaks at the first line of *dummyA.py* beause it is not able to import the module called *sub*. Weird, because the same line is executed correctly when the app runs.

As you can see, I also used the ***init**.py* in each folder, but this does not help.

Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have this structure

```
./src/dummyA.py
./src/sub/dummyB.py
./src/sub/__init__.py
./src/main.py
./src/__init__.py
./tests/test_s.py
```

fix `test_s.py`

```
from dummyA import Sup

def test_sub_sup():
```

then run

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD/src pytest -v tests
```

and you receive

```
collected 1 item                                                                                                              

tests/test_s.py::test_sub_sup PASSED                                                                                    [100%]

====================================================== 1 passed in 0.02s ======================================================
```